# Fortify complaining about lombok annotation @Data

Tags: lombok, fortify

**Fortify:** Mass Assignment: Insecure Binder Configuration

```
@Data
public class OrderRequest implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Header header;
    private List<OrderVO> orderList;

}
```

@Data lombok annotation is reporting mass assignment error in fortify.

How to resolve it? any pointers?

Comment: This seems unrelated to Lombok. Have you tried setting up your binder to disallow unused fields?

Comment: lombok with fority... cannot say its not related to lombok totally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This helped to resolve the fortify lombok issue

```
   /**
     * This is fix fortify issues as recommendation to use binder to
     * allow / disallow fields
     * @param binder
     */
    @InitBinder
    public void populateRequest(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.setDisallowedFields(new String[]{});
    }
```